# Alert Showing Twice Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i meet some trouble when i want to pass some parameters into modal and when the modal is submited the modal showing alert with parameter. and im use this modal more than once and in the first event is normal when the second event the parameters from the first event still show. how to solve it

```
function edit(id) {
    var url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>admincontroller/edit";
    alert(id + url);
    modal(id, url);
}
function delet(id) {
    var url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>admincontroller/delet";
    alert(id + url);      
    modal(id, url);
}

function modal(id, url) {
 $("#verficationuser").modal('show');

   $("#passwordverify").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert(id, url);
   });

}
```

Comment: bootstrap modal has an `hidden.bs.modal` method. It will fire when you close the modal. So you can use this method to clear the contents of the modal or reset your variables, etc. `$("#verificationuser").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() { //code here})`

Comment: where i should put that code?

Comment: still showing twice alerts

Comment: can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post it here? Makes it easy to debug your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sulaimanfahmi/r3xa68uu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go mate. Whats happening with your modal function was each time the modal function is called a submit event gets binded to the button so its called multiple times.

So solution is to unbind and bind it again. [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/r3xa68uu/1/)

Use this

```
 function modal(id, url) {
 $("#verficationuser").modal('show');

 $("#passwordverify").unbind('submit').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert(id, url);
 });
 }
```

instead of

```
function modal(id, url) {
 $("#verficationuser").modal('show');

   $("#passwordverify").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert(id, url);
   });

}
```